# Interval schedule maximization when encountering intervals with equivalent end points

Tags: algorithm, optimization, scheduling, intervals, maximize

In interval scheduling, the ***greedy solution*** which *maximizes* the schedule that contains the largest number of *"compliant intervals"* involves initially sorting the list of intervals in ascending order by the end-times/point of each interval.

What confuses me, is if two or more intervals have the same ending time.

When performing the **initial sort**, should one base the sort of the sub-range of intervals on start time?

and if so should it be in ascending or descending order?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, with the greedy based solution. All you want to optimize is to maximize no.of jobs completed. Job length is considered for finding overlap s and elimination, not for the choice.

Given list of jobs ending in same time, you will only end up in choosing 1 of them, because they all overlap. Also, there is no negative impact of choosing any of them.

Depending on application, you may want to choose the longest job or shortest job.

Hope it helps!